# Meteor Multi Input Mail

Tags: forms, input, meteor

I have a problem for my form.

In my template contact ,  i want of this message insert on my (admin) page.

This code :

```js
if(Meteor.isClient) {

  Template.contact.events({
    'submit #mymess' : function(){
      event.preventDefault();
      var nom = event.target.text.value;

      var prenom = event.target.text.value;

      var objet = event.target.text.value;

      var mail = event.target.text.value;

      var content = event.target.text.value;
      
      if(nom != ''){
        Messages.insert({
          text: nom,
          createdAt: new Date()
        });
      console.log('hello');

        event.target.text.value = '';

      }

       if(prenom != ''){
        Messages.insert({
          text: prenom,
          createdAt: new Date()
        });

        event.target.text.value = '';

}

     if(objet != ''){
        Messages.insert({
          text: objet,
          createdAt: new Date()
          });

        event.target.text.value = '';

}
     if(mail != ''){
        Messages.insert({
          text: mail,
          createdAt: new Date()
          });

        event.target.text.value = '';
}
     if(content != ''){
        Messages.insert({
          text: content,
          createdAt: new Date()
        });
        event.target.text.value = '';
}

    },
  }); 

}
```

```html
<template name="contact">
 <form id="mymess">
                    <div class="form-group">
                       <input type="text" name="prenom" class="input_mail_name " placeholder="Prénom">

                        <input type="text" name="nom" class="input_mail_name f_r" placeholder="Nom">

                         <input type="text" name="mail" class="input_mail_name long margin-top_20" placeholder="Email">

                        <input type="text" name="objet" class="input_mail_name margin-top_20 f_r" placeholder="Objet">

                        <textarea type="text" name="content" placeholder="Messages" class="input_txt_contact margin-top_20"></textarea>

                        <button type="submit" class="input_mail_send margin-top_20" id="submit">ENVOYER</button>
                    </div>   
                  </form>
</template>
```

I don't understand why my form doesn't insert on my collection Messages

And in : lib/router/collection.js

Messages = new Mongo.Collection("messages");

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add the argument 'event' to your event handler. After you've added this argument, you can access your form elements by using event.target.[name].value.

It would be cleaner to add one object for each submit.

```
if(Meteor.isClient) {

Template.contact.events({
    'submit #mymess' : function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        var nom = event.target.nom.value;

        var prenom = event.target.prenom.value;

        var objet = event.target.objet.value;

        var mail = event.target.mail.value;

        var content = event.target.content.value;

        if(nom != '' && prenom !='' && objet!='' && mail!='' && content !=''){
            Messages.insert({
                nom: nom,
                prenom: prenom,
                objet: objet,
                mail: mail,
                content: content,
                createdAt: new Date()
            });
            console.log('hello');

            event.target.nom.value = '';
            event.target.prenom.value = '';
            event.target.objet.value = '';
            event.target.mail.value = '';
            event.target.content.value = '';

        }

    }
});

}
```

Comment: Merci beaucoup ! C'est exactement ca !

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in the event object as a parameter to your function:

```
if(Meteor.isClient) {

  Template.contact.events({
    'submit #mymess' : function( event ){
      event.preventDefault();
      var nom = event.target.text.value;

      var prenom = event.target.text.value;
```